# Error on installing react-native-wifi-hotspot

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error on installing the library **react-native-wifi-hotspot**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-wifi-hotspot.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-wifi-hotspot:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at makeError (/home/prafulla/Projects/AnySend/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/prafulla/Projects/AnySend/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/prafulla/Projects/AnySend/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/prafulla/Projects/AnySend/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

**Steps I followed**

Installed using NPM

`npm i --save react-native-wifi-hotspot`

Linked the assets

`react-native link react-native-wifi-hotspot`

Comment: could you find solution?

Comment: Nope, i created my own library instead using native code.